# Prolog.Объединить два списка по условию

Tags: list, prolog, swi-prolog

Нужно все нечётные и превышающие заданное число значения из второго списка добавить в первый.
Я сделал так:

```
add_to_list(L, X, [X|L]).
isEven(X):- 1 is X mod 2.

add_even(_, [], _, _).
add_even(FirstList, [X|SecondList], ResultList, Z):-
    isEven(X),!,
    X > Z,!,
    add_to_list(FirstList, X, ResultList),
    add_even(FirstList, SecondList, ResultList, Z).
add_even(FirstList, [_|SecondList], ResultList, X):-
    add_even(FirstList, SecondList, ResultList, X).
```

Однако он вообще не выдаёт никаких списков в результате, вместо этого выдаёт true/false

```
?- add_even([1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], X, 4).
Result: false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь у вас лишний оператор отсечения после `isEven(X)`, условие нечетности и условие `X > Z` общее и если хотя бы одна из этих частей ложна, то нужно продолжать поиск решения дальше, то есть перейти к третьему правилу `add_even`. А с оператором отсечения при нахождении нечетного числа меньшего Z вы не позволяете Прологу использовать третье правило.

---

**UPD**

Предикат `add_to_list` вернет true тогда, когда третий параметр представляет собой список с головой `X` и телом `L`. при первом проходе `ResultList` еще не конкретизирован, поэтому происходит согласование, при втором проходе `ResultList` уже конкретизирован, и согласование невозможно, так как голова списка не равна `X`.

В таком случае добавление элементов в результирующий список нужно использую или еще один параметр или список `FirstList`:

```
add_even(X, [], X, _).
add_even(FirstList, [X|SecondList], ResultList, Z):-
    isEven(X),
    X > Z,!,
    add_even([X| FirstList], SecondList, ResultList, Z).
add_even(FirstList, [_|SecondList], ResultList, X):-
    add_even(FirstList, SecondList, ResultList, X).
```

Добавлять элементы сразу в `ResultList` не получится, потому что при выходе из рекурсии значения `ResultList` будут откатываться назад.

Comment: Спасибо ещё раз) Единственная проблема осталось, он не может добавить больше одного подходящего по условию элемента. Один добавляет нормально. А если два и больше то пишет false

Comment: @ВикторТитов обновил ответ, посмотрите